# shorthand promise in if statement not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an if statement like so.

```
if(!(this._lf.getItem('test').then(result => result))) {
    console.log(null);
} else {
    console.log('Yay');
}
```

but I can't seem to get it to work right...

if I console.log the result from the getItem like so

```
this._lf.getItem('te').then(result => console.log(result));
```

I get null returned back,

but if I do it this way

```
console.log(this._lf.getItem('te').then(result => result);
```

I get back this object...

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: 
Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: null
__proto__: Object
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here??

I recently switched from localStorage as my offline data storage to localForage and In localStorage, I can easily check if a key is null by doing something like this.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('key')) {
    // do something
}
```

So I'm just trying to do the equivalent here

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: "I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here??" Using asynchronous API synchronously.

Comment: `.then(result => result)` is redundant and doesn't make the code suddenly synchronous

Comment: Feel free to read [Up and Running with Asynchronous JavaScript](https://medium.com/@rcepeda1993/async-js-the-complete-guide-670b4cf906c6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `getItem` returns a `Promise`, you can't check its value immediately. You might put it in an `async` function so you can `await` its value inside the `if`:

```
if(!await this._lf.getItem('test')) {
  console.log(null);
} else {
  console.log('Yay');
}
```

Or, you could repeat yourself less by using the conditional operator:

```
console.log(
  await this._lf.getItem('test')
  ? 'Yay'
  : null
);
```

Note that `.then(result => result);` does nothing at all - you can leave that off entirely.

Comment: Thanks! This helped! I wasn't entirely sure how to make this work